# How to Pause Chromecast Screen Mirroring

Tags: chromecast

*TL;DR:* How do I, when casting my device's screen through the Chromecast app to a Chromecast, pause the stream? Aka, the Chromecast shows a fixed image of my screen while I change screens on my phone.

**More Info**

Specifically, I've been using my phone to help me run a D&D campaign. I want to be able to show pre-designed maps on the screen, but also be able to swap to my notes on Google Drive (obviously without the players seeing those notes). I know I can stop/start streaming, but that doesn't leave the image on the screen, and is a lot of extra work.

The low-tech solution I have right now is just using a notebook for my meet notes, but I would like to be able to use my phone for most of it if I can.